# How do I access the datafields in the source object of a jqxlistbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to bind a JQXListbox to JSON data and display two fields in the result.

I want to access the datafields in the source object as strings in order to concatenate them so as I can set the resulting string as the displayMember property of jqxListBox.  I've tried calling ToString() on the source.datafields[x] array but that doesn't work either.

I'm not sure if the terminology was correct there.   Thanks for any help you can give.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.classic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="jqxlistbox"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var string;

            $(document).ready(function() {

                // prepare the data
                var source =
                        {
                            datatype: "json",
                            datafields: [
                                {name: 'firstname'},
                                {name: 'lastname'}
                            ],
                            url: 'my url is here'

                        };
                        string = source.datafields[0] + source.datafields[1];
                        alert(string);
                var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

                $("#jqxlistbox").jqxListBox(
                        {
                            source: dataAdapter,
                            theme: 'classic',
                            width: 200,
                            height: 250,
                            displayMember: 'string',
                            valueMember: 'firstname'
                        });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the "beforeLoadComplete" callback of the jqxDataAdapter plug-in will help you to customize the loaded data through the plug-in. For more information about that function, please look at: [jqxDataAdapter plug-in](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdataadapter/jquery-data-adapter.htm)

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look at this and let you know how I get on.